# how to print a result of linq query from controller in the view?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the follow code in the controller

```
  public ActionResult Linq()
        {
            List<region> Regiones = db.region.ToList();
            List<comuna> Comunas = db.comuna.ToList();

            var  resultado = from r in Regiones
                            join c in Comunas on r.r_id equals c.c_region
                            where r.r_id == 8
                            select new
                            {
                                region = r.r_region,
                                comuna = c.c_comuna
                            };
            ViewBag.resultado = resultado;
            return View();
        }
```

and this in the view

```
 @{ 
                           foreach(var a in ViewBag.resultado)
                           {
                              <tr><td>
                                  @a.comuna
                              </td></tr> 
                           }
                       }
```

but when this run, i have the follow error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' no contiene una definición para 'comuna'.

What happened? how I print all "comuna" in the view?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you cast it `.ToList()` after the linq query?

Comment: I tried, not work that way. Thanks!!

Comment: @MaartenHeebink the foreach will already iterate the `IEnumerable`, so putting it in a list is not necessary. Megatron's solution should work.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on where you fill your `ViewBag`? To see if it actually is being filled, and with what it is being filled?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Thanks for the correction

Comment: @MaartenHeebink is being filled, when print this on view only with @a show {region:some, comuna:some} ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible solution is create a new type for result like

```
public class Address //some good name
{
    public int Region  {get;set;};
    public string Comuna {get;set;} ;
}
```

them modify your action

```
public ActionResult Linq()
{
    List<region> Regiones = db.region.ToList();
    List<comuna> Comunas = db.comuna.ToList();

    var  resultado = from r in Regiones
                    join c in Comunas on r.r_id equals c.c_region
                    where r.r_id == 8
                    select new Address
                    {
                        Region = r.r_region,
                        Comuna = c.c_comuna
                    };
    return View(resultado);
}
```

and change view:

```
 @model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Address>

 @{ 
   foreach(var a in Model)
   {
      <tr><td>
          @a.Comuna
      </td></tr> 
   }
}
```

Comment: it work! Thanks!! 
but why above, I write only @ and show {region:some,comuna:some} ?

Comment: @DiegoFlores Glad to have been of help. Where did you put @?

Comment: my view on the Visual studio, not in this post (sorry my "tarzan" english Im Chilean)